# Dodged Bar Chart featuring multiple binary variables in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart, tidyverse

I would like to create a plot which shows the count of "Yes" votes in three different variables (Total, Interview, Hire) based on a third variable (Year).It's also worth noting there's no actual Total variable, rather it's just the total observations

I am trying to do this in ggplot2 however everything I've tried hasn't produced the results I'm looking for. I can easily get one dodged and plotted using geom_bar, but I am unsure how to represent 2 different variables.

```
 app <- structure(list(Applicant_Name = c("Aaraf", "Alaina", 
 "Aleena", "Alejandra", "Alexa", "Alexander", 
 "Alexandra", "Alexandra", "Alexandria", 
 "Alexis"), Interview = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
 "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), Hire = c("No", "No", "Yes", 
 "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), Year = c(2022, 2020, 
 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2022), School = c("School of Business", 
 "Columbian Coll of Arts & Sci", "Milken Inst Sch of Public Hlth", 
 "Columbian Coll of Arts & Sci", "School of Engin & App Sc", "Columbian Coll of Arts & Sci", 
 "Columbian Coll of Arts & Sci", "Columbian Coll of Arts & Sci", 
 "School of Business", "Columbian Coll of Arts & Sci"), Major = c("Pre-Business Administration", 
 "Biological Anthropology", "Public Health", "Biological Anthropology", 
 "Systems Engineering", "Arts & Sciences", "Neuroscience", "English", 
 "International Business", "Arts & Sciences"), Ethnicity = c("Black or African American", 
 "White", "White", "Nonresident alien", "White", "White", "Race/ethnicity unknown", 
 "Two or More Race Codes", "Black or African American", "Black or African American"
 ), Sex = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
 "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), GPA = c(3.221428, 
 3.230158, 3.429268, 3.576595, 3.86, 4, 3.460759, 3.89315, 3.227631, 
 1.433333)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
 "data.frame"))

 ggplot(app, aes(Year, ..count..)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Hire), position = "dodge")
```

Ideally, I would like a plot showing our total number of applicants (all observations) next to total number of Interview=Yes next to total number of Hire=Yes, broken down by year.

Here is a visual example with my lovely artistic ability.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYr8w.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to directly get the data you want to plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
app2 <- app %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(Total = n(),
            Interviewed = sum(Interview == "Yes"),
            Hired = sum(Hire == "Yes")) %>% 
  gather( "category", "counts", -Year)
```

And then plotting is straight forward:

```
ggplot(app2, aes(Year, counts)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = category), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Aweosome! Yeah this is exactly it; Now do you know how I can have the biggest one (total) be left most and then the smaller ones follow ? So total, interviewed, Hired as opposed to the opp?

Comment: sorry meant to tag

Comment: Just explicitly make the factor levels. so add `%>% 
  mutate(category = factor(category, levels = c("Total","Interviewed","Hired")))` to the end of the app2 pipe